# In IIS, Is there a way I can enforce clients to use certain SSL cipher suites depending on what URL/path they visit?

Tags: encryption, ssl, webserver, iis, tls

I have an IIS 11.0 webserver that supports TLS. Lets say my site is called https://www.example.com. There are two different sections to my website. For example, the URL https://www.example.com/partA/pageA.html and https://www.example.com/partB/pageB.html

What I am looking to do is to enforce certain TLS cipher suites depending on what part of the site my clients connect to. For example, for /partB as a requirement I need to enforce only strong TLS cipher suites so clients can only connect using them. For part A i dont really care what is used. (The TLS versions available arent important as I dont believe its possible to do that without disabling them on the server)

I understand that Apache supports what im looking to do in mod_ssl by using the the Location tag (as detailed in https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html)

But i cant seem to find any info about IIS supporting the same. Can anyone help?
Any information is appreciated !

Thanks

Esmonde.